# Preassign decision variables of a tupel set

Tags: tuples, cplex, opl

I am trying to solve a Flexible job-shop problem and want to add some precedence constraints additionally. Therefore i want to preassign/ constraint some decision variables iterated over a tuple.
While the generic formulations of constraints and the access of the tupledata with the forall-operator do not seem to be a problem (as in (1)), I am struggling with the formulation of a specific decision variable as "the type boolean can not be used for <>" in (2).

(1) forall (t in DATA)            // (2) if Operation is not assigned to ressource k Start- & End-
StartingTime[t]  + CompletionTime[t] <= x[t]*L;  // time = 0

// 84 Constraints, 136 Variablen (45 Binär, 91 andere)

(2) forall(t in DATA)                                      //
jobCompletionTime[t.job == 1] <= StartingTime[t.job == 10];

My Model without the constraints:
tuple Columns { // Deklaration des Tupeltyp
int operation;  // Operation
int job;         // Job
int pos;           // Position der Operation in job
string posID;
string ressource;  // Ressource
float prozesszeit; // Prozesszeit
};

{Columns} DATA= ...;  // Deklaration Tupelmenge
//Columns TupelTeilmenge = item(DATA, i);  --> Tupelteilmenge (i. Tupel in Tabelle)
//int praezedenz[jobs][jobs]=...;                   // Vorrangmatrix

// Entscheidungsvariablen
dvar boolean x[DATA];                // 1 falls Operation ij auf Ressource k bearbeitet wird (Auswahl des jeweiligen Tupels); 0 sonst
dvar float+ StartingTime[DATA];      // Startzeit des Tupels
dvar float+ CompletionTime[DATA];    // Endzeit des Tupels
dvar boolean Y[DATA][DATA];                // 1, falls Operation ij (tupel t ) nachfolger von Operation i'j' (tupel t2) auf Ressource k; 0 sonst
dvar float+ jobCompletionTime[DATA]; // Achtung: jobs mehrfach einzelnen Operationen zugeordnet
dvar float+ maxCompletionTime;

minimize (maxCompletionTime);

subject to {

Comment: (1) forall (t in DATA)     
         StartingTime[t]  + CompletionTime[t] <= x[t]*L;                                                                //   if Operation is not assigned to Ressource k Start- & End-  time = 0

Answer (score 0):

in the OPL examples you should have a look at

**The flexible job-shop scheduling**

> This problem is an extension of the classical Job-Shop Scheduling
> problem which allows an operation to be processed by any machine from
> a given set. The problem is to assign each operation to a machine and
> to order the operations on the machines such that the maximal
> completion time (makespan) of all operations is minimized.
>
> To access this example, go to: examples/opl/sched_jobshopflex.

and the precedence constraint is

```
forall (j in Jobs, o1 in Ops, o2 in Ops: o1.jobId==j && o2.jobId==j && o2.pos==1+o1.pos)
    endBeforeStart(ops[o1],ops[o2]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I had already seen this example and the regarding dokumentation before but still tried to implement a model formulation without the use of the sequence/interval variables and the specific funktions (noOverlap, endBeforeStart) I am probably gonna change my approach. But therefore - as it is also relevant independend from the model: Is it possible to formulate with common operators, that the decision variable CompletionTime[DATA] is <= as the decision variable StartingTime[DATA] while both refering to a set of tuple with information regarding job, operation and time?